# Show that $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is skew-symmetric if $\det(A+M)=0$ for all M skew-symmetric, with $n$ odd.

Tags: matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $n$ be an odd integer, and $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that, for all $M\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ skew-symmetric, we have: $$ \det(A+M)=0$$
Show that $A$ is skew-symmetric.

What I did so far:
Nothing much really…

- $\det(A) = 0$ plugging $M=0$
- $\det\left(\dfrac{A+A^T}{2}\right) = 0$ plugging $M=\dfrac{A^T-A}{2}$
- $\det(M)=0$ for all $M$ skew-symmetric, since $n$ is odd

Comment: One possible approach: reduce the problem to the special case where $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thank you, I think I solved it for the diagonal case. But how does this help solving the general case?

Comment: Absorb the skew-symmetric part into $M$ and change the orthonormal basis such that the symmetric part of $A$ becomes diagonal.

Comment: Oh that’s clever. Thanks again!